# pointer confusion in c .can someone explain the execution of this code

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct node
    {
        int a, b, c;
    };

    struct node num = {3, 5, 6};
    struct node *ptr = & num;
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)ptr + 1 + (3-2)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The behaviour is *undefined*. It violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: @WeatherVane incorrect, there is no strict aliasing violation! This has been allowed ever since C89. It is accessing array (of 1) out of bounds why it is undefined.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and your answer is incorrect too. The expression is accessing the 3rd element of a supposed array. It would have been less of a crime with `struct node { int a[3]; };`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It does; there is no array and no guaranteed the members will use no padding like in an array. It's obfuscated bad code which pays the price. Such code should be deleted and burried. Dracula code: it always comes back.

Comment: @WeatherVane strict aliasing says that totally unrelated pointer types cannot be used to modify / access objects. There is no padding at the beginning so the cast to `(int *)` is fine, there would be no undefined behaviour since it is the `int` object that is being accessed as an `int`. But the member `a` is *as if it were an array of 1* when it comes to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OP's code is `*( (int*)ptr + 2 );` which makes the assumption that there is no padding.

Comment: And it would be still wrong even if there were no padding.

Comment: So it *is* wrong now? I did not condone it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num` is a structure that is initialized to `a=3`, `b=5` and `c=6`. 
`ptr` is a pointer that points to the structure. Everything is fine until the `printf` line.

The construct

```
*((int*)ptr + 1 + (3-2)))
```

first casts `ptr` that points  into a pointer to `int`:

```
(int*)ptr
```

The pointer points to the member `a` and is well-defined.

Now 1 is added to this pointer:

```
(int*)ptr + 1
```

The pointer points to just past the member `a` in the struct. Everything is well-defined unless this pointer is dereferenced. Finally `3 - 2` i.e. `1` is once more added to the resulting pointer.

```
(int*)ptr + 1
```

Behaviour is now undefined.

```
(int*)ptr + 1 + (3 - 2)
```

Then this invalid pointer is dereferenced causing undefined behaviour once more.

```
*((int*)ptr + 1 + (3 - 2))
```

The reason that the number 6 was printed and that seems like it is the 3rd member of the struct was just a fluke ;)

Comment: Really? An answer? There is not even a **specific** question.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite ah I thought the question was "what does this code do", but it was "can someone explain the execution of the code?" for which the answer is "yes, someone can".

Comment: Point is, "explain this code" questions without a specific problem are way OT. Such questions are often given as homework to make the students learn reading code and have an example how to do things. But even if not, they are too broad and should be closed. (and that one can be understood with basic C knowledge taught by every C book. (said that: it invokes UB.

Comment: so the correct answer to question is "yes". But thats too short for SO, and not what the questioner probably wants

Comment: @pm100: Yes. Unfortunately you drew the wrong conclusion.

Comment: thanks,can you also tell me how this is executed then,I think these 2 questions contradict each other
char *arr[] = { "ant", "bat", "cat", "dog", "egg", "fly" };
function(arr);

void function(char **ptr)
{
 char *ptr1;
 ptr1 = (ptr += sizeof(int))[-2];
 printf("%s\n", ptr1);
}

Comment: @AyushyaRao that depends on the size of `int`; on most generic computing platforms it is either 2 or 4 - then it is just equivalent to `char *ptr1 = ptr[4 - 2]` or `char *ptr = arr[2 - 2]`.

Comment: Perfectly defined

Answer (score 0):

lets simplify

```
 printf("%d\n", *((int*)ptr + 1 + (3-2)));
```

to

```
 int *ip = (int*)ptr;
 int *ip2 = ip + 2;
 int v = *ip2;
 printf("%d\n", v);
```

ie.

'treating ptr as a pointer to a list of ints, display the value of the third one'.

The first step , treating a pointer to that struct as a pointer to an array of ints is taking advantage (misusing?) the fact that the first 3 fields are almost certainly going to be stored as 3 consecutive integers . Its a bit dodgy and I would hesitate to do it. I leave it to others to indicate whether or not its correct, in a strictly standard conforming way. I doubt it since we might have padding issues on some platforms